# What sort of seasonal changes might exist that we don't see on earth?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, seasons

NASA recently shared a photo that used a term "araneiform terrain" and said that the terrain formation was an effect of seasonal changes we don't see on earth. [NASA publication](http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/jpl/jamming-with-the-spiders-from-mars#.W0lAyc9aNoA.gmail)

How would I go about discovering or formulating seasonal changes we wouldn't see on earth but would be totally feasible in another planetary setting? Star configuration (binary, red dwarf) and satellite configuration are open for suggestions as well.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This has the potential of being a great question, but it's pretty broad right now.  We need your help to narrow the scope into something more appropriate.  Can you give us your starting point?  Tell us about your solar system, planet, and its moons and we can help you with how those circumstances can be used to gain a broad understanding of such seasonal changes.  Without those facts, we'd be writing a textbook, and that's out of scope for this site.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I was not at the point of designing a specific world yet.

Comment: No problem, but if you think about it, a process that designed seasons for any arbitrary world under any arbitrary sun is a lot of variables.

Answer (score 4):

There is an exoplanet that has an axial tilt that changes drastically on a scale of mere years causing essentially Game Of Thrones-style seasons (perhaps a weird moon arrangement would allow this?)

A moderately eccentric planet (about 0.25) around an F type star (~2 earth year orbit) with a 45-degree axial tilt with perihelion in "April" would have, around 20 degrees North, a distinct "greater summer", "lesser summer", "greater winter", and "lesser winter".

On an eccentric tidelocked world around a red dwarf, the year would be only a couple Earth weeks long. Around the terminator lie libration zones which experience both day and night -- "seasons" of the 2-week year. If the planet is close enough, only the libration zones and nightside would be habitable.